# Haskell Platform through Macports

Tags: haskell, macports, haskell-platform

I have installed the Haskell Platform through MacPorts. Although many Haskell libraries are available as MacPorts packages, some are not. What is the proper way to install them? (without inconsistencies or duplications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cabal

```
cabal install <packagename>
```

One nice thing about cabal is, by default, it puts stuff in ~/.cabal/, so you won't have to worry about it conflicting with your system files.

Comment: But it will install the packages for one user account only, right? And is Cabal smart enough not to reinstall dependencies already installed through MacPorts?

Comment: By default, it will only install for the account using it (I think there is a way to make it systemwide, but have never tried).  It is pretty lightweight though, and installs dependencies, plus is always up to date (as long as you type `cabal update`).  I don't know about your second question though, I usually try to keep libs out of system files altogether.